# Too few arguments for view error with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

I'm having a problem with laravel., I'm trying to send the variable $codes on my view :

```
$codes = Code::where('user', $id)->get();
return view('user.edit', ['user' => $user,'codes' => $codes]);
```

But I get that error `Too few arguments to function e(), 0 passed in`
The variable $user goes well but not the variable code, anyone have an idea for a solution? 
Thank you all

Comment: Seems like you forget to define `$user` variable.

Comment: This could also happen if you have an empty `{{}}` in your view

Comment: the error is coming from the view not the controller

Comment: @apokryfos Thank you! This was annoying me for too long, feel free to add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

use this:-

```
return view('user.edit')->with('codes',$codes);
```

you can get the user with :-

```
Auth::user()->name;
```

Comment: But if I want send other argument, is not possible to make a array ?

Comment: In Laravel 7.x how you made the view is completely good, and you shouldn't go with this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure, if you are following Laravel naming conventions, in your eloquent query the column name is user_id and not user. Also if you are using such querys, and you have foreign, you can define relations in your models, like the following:

Code Model

```
public function user
{
$this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

User Model

```
public function codes
{
$this->hasMany(Code::class);
}
```

Instead of line

```
$codes = Code::where('user', $id)->get();
```

You can go with:

```
$codes = $user->codes();
```

If you don't have the foreigns in your database

```
$codes = Code::where('user_id', $id)->get();
```

If non of these helps, please dd() your variables before returning the view, and share result with me in comment. In laravel 7 how you return view is good.

Comment: I did set up the 1:n relationship and it works for the recording. However, it is now impossible for me to access my list of codes corresponding to a user. `$user= Users::find($id);
  dd($user->codes);` the dd() returns null

Comment: Your model name is User, so it's User::find($id) right?

Answer (score 0):

The [`e`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/helpers#method-e) function is used by blade templates to escape HTML code and in essence the code:

```
{{ $somevar }}
```

becomes

```
<?php echo e($somevar); ?>
```

so you can get this error if you provide blade with an empty `{{}}` since that will become:

```
<?php echo e(); ?>
```

and `e` has 1 required parameter.